# CSRF Token validation when processing

Tags: php, csrf, csrf-protection

I have seen questions on this topic but cant seem to find a solution.  On my index page, at the top I am simply doing

```
<?php
session_start();

function generate_secure_token($length = 16) {
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
}

$_SESSION['token'] = generate_secure_token();
$token = $_SESSION['token'];

?>
```

I then set `$token` as a hidden field within my form.  My question is relating to the processing of the form.  At the moment I have

```
if ( empty( $_POST[ 'csrf_token' ] ) )
{
    $errors['token'] = 'Something went wrong';
}
```

So it simply checks that a token exists.  Is this enough?  I have seen other examples recreating the token and then comparing it with the session token, but not sure if I need this?

Any advice on how I can validate this properly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _"Is this enough?"_ No, you need to check that the token POSTed by the user matches the token you created earlier. Otherwise, the user can just send any crap as a token, which kinda defeats the purpose of using it.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [OWASP CSRF Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and then if you can, implementing something like [CSRFProtector](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFProtector_Project)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the given token to your session token to be sure that the introduced token is valid:

```
if ( empty( $_POST[ 'csrf_token' ] ) ||  
     $_POST[ 'csrf_token' ] != $_SESSION['token'])
{
    $errors['token'] = 'Something went wrong';
}
```

Comment: That is vulnerable to timing attacks.

Comment: After implementing CSRF solution hidden field comparing server side , the problem is , when open new tab with same URL then hidden filed comes null.Server side condition is if CSRF hidden field null then its attack.is it expected behavior ?